# how to execute a loop n times in 1 second

Tags: java, loops, timer

I am trying to execute couple of instructions or a function N times in one second.
How can i do this in java?
 As follows...

```
//in one second
while(N)
{
  printf(".........");
  int x=0;
  printf("The value of x is ");
}
```

but the question actually goes little deeper.. I am trying to plot pixels manually and I want the no of rotations per second effect... so basically, it has to execute N times for a second (But this is done infinitely )

thanks in advance

Comment: If this is just homework you can use a busy loop checking the current time in each iteration

Comment: You cannot be sure exactly how many times a cycle runs in your loop in one minute if you are talking about regular OS's. To be sure you need a RTOS or guess it by measuring the time between each cycle.

Comment: Do you want it to run every amount of N in 1 second or just as many of N as possible in exactly 1 second?

Comment: I'm am fairly certain the poster will be happy with answers that run "suitably close" to a second.

Answer (score 7):

I would flip the issue: don't limit the loop to N times in a second. Instead, process N units of work evenly distributed over the desired time.

That is, compute how much time has passed since the *start* (or *previous work*), interpolate that into the *rate of work*, and *do that much work* (factor in the start/previous time and the amount of work that has been done). This is the fundamental underpinning of many game/animation engines - a ["delta time"](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/67/delta-time-and-framerate-independence/page-1).

Then call `yield` at the end of each loop to "be nice" - or rather, to prevent eating 99%+ CPU usage! The yield itself has a minimum resolution<sup>1</sup>, but the effects are generally adequate, especially when interpolating suitably.

Because an interpolation approach is used, this should work for all N (that *can* run in the allotted time), even if it means doing many more N each loop. It is also possible that no work might be done any particular loop for a small N but the `yield` makes this sort of "extra busy looping" cheap in terms of CPU utilization<sup>2</sup>.

---

Here is some pseudo-code to print out 20 "x"s in a second, where `now` returns fractional seconds:

```
rate = 20       // per second - "N times per second"
done = 0
goal = 1 * rate // same as rate for 1 second
start = now()
while done < goal:
    target = floor((now() - start) * rate)
    work = (target - done) // work might be 0, that's okay
    for 0 upto work:
         print("x")
    done += work
    yield()
```

In this case it is easy to interpolate off of the start time because of the constant rate formula. Using a "delta time" based off the time since the last work (or loop) is similar and is suitable when there is no discrete formula, but is slightly more complex and can lead to subtle drift errors.

---

<sup>1</sup> The time resolution of an *actual* `sleep/yield` is implementation-dependent and varies by by system. For instance, it might range from as low as [1ms on Linux to 10-15ms on windows](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml).

<sup>2</sup> In *addition to* dealing with a time delta, the `sleep` period can be altered, as per Dariusz Wawer's answer. However, this adds complexity and a simple `yield` is often sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can never be sure it will happen exactly N times per second, but it goes like this:

```
long taskTime = 0;
long sleepTime = 1000/N;
while (true) {
  taskTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //do something
  taskTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-taskTime;
  if (sleepTime-taskTime > 0 ) {
    Thread.sleep(sleepTime-taskTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that , those instructions cant execute in one tick...
So we can make it sleep for 1000/N

Comment: That's not a problem - measure the task time and subtract it from the sleep time. I will edit the answer...

Comment: Nit: This will only work approximately for smaller N (say 30 or less). For larger N, multiple N will need to be done *each time* before the sleep.

Comment: @pst you say N<30, but why won't it work i.e. for N=50? I see a problem for N>300, since millis time precision is often 3ms.

Comment: The problem isn't the precision/accuracy of `currentTimeMillis`: the problem is the minimum sleep duration (which is much more), since "do something" is presumed to be equivalent to "do one N". I don't recall the exact minimum yield durations, but I go by "1/30th of a second" on Windows as a general rule. It could be much lower on Linux, for instance.

Comment: @pst care to post a link or something? I managed to find this: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml but the graph shows that there shouldn't be any problems with sleep duration

Comment: Nice link, see: "In Linux, this interrupt period is generally 1ms in recent kernels (2.6.8 onwards). In Windows, the scheduler's interrupt period is normally around 10 or 15 milliseconds" - so it looks like my rule was slightly off on Windows and way off on Linux ;-)

Comment: Thnx just what I needed :) to not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be acurate with the proposed solutions. Instead of calculate the gap between iterations, calculate the absolute time when the next iteration should be executed. This is more accurate because iterations don't depend on previous ones.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long msPerIteration = 1000000/iterationsPerSecond;
long i=0;
while (true) {
    // do stuff

    long msWaiting = startTime + (msPerIteration * ++i) - System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (msWaiting > 0)
        Thread.sleep(msWaiting);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to write a game loop today. I used an overflow variable that makes sure that the next tick will wait longer if the previous ones were too quick. Every tick removes half of the overflow and uses it to influence the frametime.

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            long overflow = 0; // The greater the overflow, the slower the game had calculated the last tick, and the shorter this tick's wait needs to be
            long lastStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            while(true) {
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                overflow += (startTime - lastStartTime) - 16666667; // 16.67 milliseconds = 60 fps

                tick();

                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long waitTime = 16666667 - (endTime - startTime) - overflow / 2;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime / 1000000, (int) (waitTime % 1000000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                overflow /= 2; // Do not remove all overflow at once to prevent oscillation of ticktime
                lastStartTime = startTime;
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to `while(true)`.

Check the time in milliseconds before your `while` loop. At the end of the `while` loop get the time in milliseconds and see if 1000 of them have passed. If so `break`.

Comment: This helps... but the question actually goes little deeper..
I am trying to plot pixels manually and I want the no of rotations per second effect... so basically, it has to execute N times for a second (But this is done infinitely )

Comment: So this will... execute for a second regardless of how many times the loop is repeated. That's not what the point was, is it?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. From what I understand is that you want the loop to execute exactly N times in a particular second.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code:

```
Create Timer t;
t.Start;
int counter = N;
While ((t.Elapsedtime < 1 Second) AND (N > 0))
{
    call your_function();
    N--;
}

your_function()
{
    printf(".........");
    int x=0;
    printf("The value of x is ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start <= 1000) {
  // Your code goes here
}
```

All it takes care is that your code will be looped over for 1000 milliseconds. The number of times it's done is uncertain and may vary on each run.